# Activity is recreated after called finish() on it

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing a voip application which makes basically use of a main Activity (XTabsContainer) and a Service (NativeService). The main Activity is always started (i.e. from the SplashScreen Activity) with flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

In the main Activity I have an OptionsMenu with just one item used to exit from the application with the following function:

```
public void exit(){
    Log.d(TAG, "exit()");
    mExitThread = new ExitThread();
    mExitThread.start();
    this.finish();
}
```

The ExitThread() just closes up some stuff and terminates the Service:

```
private class ExitThread extends Thread
{
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Unregistration thread");
        INgnSipService sipService = Engine.getInstance().getSipService();
        int count = 0;
        if (sipService.isRegistered())
        {
            sipService.unRegister();
            while (count <= NativeService.mTimeout && sipService.isRegistered())
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                count++;
            }
            // Exit for timeout
            if (count > NativeService.mTimeout)
                Log.w(TAG, "Exiting Unregistration thread for TIMEOUT");
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Exiting Unregistration thread");
        }
        if (!Engine.getInstance().stop()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to stop engine");
        }   
    }   
}
```

Than finish() should close the main Activity.

What happens very randomly is that after finish() is called, the main Activity is started again, and I don't understand why, so I need to click the "Exit" button from the OptionsMenu a second time to actually exit from the app.

Following the log when this happens. In particular the first call to the exit() function is made at 04-26 10:29:21.580.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
## Raise the app in foreground

04-26 10:29:16.020: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): onResume()
04-26 10:29:16.020: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): TabsFragmentActivity handleAction(): ACTION_NOTIFY_HIDDEN_CALL value=false
04-26 10:29:18.840: W/ResourceType(32540): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
04-26 10:29:19.075: D/dalvikvm(32540): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1601K, 26% free 14639K/19527K, paused 22ms+4ms, total 171ms

## Press Exit button in the OptionsMenu

04-26 10:29:21.580: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): exit()
04-26 10:29:21.605: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): Starting Unregistration thread
04-26 10:29:21.605: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnConfigurationService(32540): stopping...
04-26 10:29:21.615: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnHistoryService(32540): Stopping
04-26 10:29:21.615: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnStorageService(32540): stopping...
04-26 10:29:21.615: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnContactService(32540): stopping...
04-26 10:29:21.620: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnContactService(32540): Observer Looper exit()
04-26 10:29:21.620: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService(32540): stopping...
04-26 10:29:21.870: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSipService(32540): GSM Observer stopped...
04-26 10:29:21.870: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnSoundService(32540): stopping...
04-26 10:29:21.870: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnNetworkService(32540): Stopping...
04-26 10:29:21.970: D/it.domain.myapp.NativeService(32540): onDestroy()
04-26 10:29:21.970: D/org.doubango.ngn.NgnNativeService(32540): onDestroy()

## Here the main Activity is started again

04-26 10:29:21.980: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): XTabsContainer()
04-26 10:29:21.980: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): onCreate()
04-26 10:29:21.980: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnNetworkService(32540): acquireNetworkLock()
04-26 10:29:21.985: D/org.doubango.ngn.services.impl.NgnNetworkService(32540): netType=1 and netSubType=0
04-26 10:29:22.000: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): initialiseTabHost()
04-26 10:29:22.005: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): TabFragRecents()
04-26 10:29:22.005: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): onCreateView()
04-26 10:29:22.015: D/AbsListView(32540): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-26 10:29:22.015: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): onActivityCreated()
04-26 10:29:22.015: D/it.domain.myapp.ContactsListAdapter(32540): ContactsListAdapter()
04-26 10:29:22.015: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): MyRecentsListAdapter()
04-26 10:29:22.020: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): onStart()
04-26 10:29:22.030: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): BadgeNumberUpdate()
04-26 10:29:22.030: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): BadgeNumberUpdate(): SIP NOT REGISTERED
04-26 10:29:22.155: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): onResume()
04-26 10:29:22.155: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): TabsFragmentActivity handleAction(): ACTION_NOTIFY_HIDDEN_CALL value=false
04-26 10:29:22.395: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:22.395: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

## Here the previous main Activity is actually destroyed and the new-created main Activity shows up

04-26 10:29:22.395: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): onDestroy
04-26 10:29:22.410: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): onDestroy

## The new-created main Activity continues its life

04-26 10:29:30.635: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): TabFragContacts()
04-26 10:29:30.635: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): onCreateView()
04-26 10:29:30.670: D/AbsListView(32540): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-26 10:29:30.675: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): onActivityCreated()
04-26 10:29:30.675: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): Pressed button: 2131296425
04-26 10:29:30.680: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): onResume()
04-26 10:29:30.695: E/SensorManager(32540): thread start
04-26 10:29:30.700: D/SensorManager(32540): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,+*a):8(
04-26 10:29:30.790: D/it.domain.myapp.ContactsListAdapter(32540): ContactsListAdapter()
04-26 10:29:30.795: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): updateSections()
04-26 10:29:30.855: E/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): onPostExecute(): Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 10:29:30.855: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:30.855: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:30.860: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:30.860: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:35.365: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): Recents Tab Pressed!
04-26 10:29:35.365: D/SensorManager(32540): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,+*a):8(
04-26 10:29:35.370: D/Sensors(32540): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
04-26 10:29:35.370: I/Sensors(32540): sendDelay --- 200000000
04-26 10:29:35.370: D/SensorManager(32540): JNI - sendDelay
04-26 10:29:35.370: I/SensorManager(32540): Set normal delay = true
04-26 10:29:35.380: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): onResume()
04-26 10:29:35.380: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): updateSections()
04-26 10:29:35.380: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): sendActionMsg()
04-26 10:29:35.380: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): sendActionMsg(): SIP NOT REGISTERED
04-26 10:29:35.475: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32540): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-26 10:29:35.505: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32540): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-26 10:29:35.505: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32540): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
04-26 10:29:37.030: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:37.030: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:38.950: D/it.domain.myapp.FragmentServices(32540): onCreateView()
04-26 10:29:38.970: D/AbsListView(32540): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-26 10:29:38.970: D/it.domain.myapp.FragmentServices(32540): buildData()
04-26 10:29:38.970: D/it.domain.myapp.FragmentServices(32540): putData()
04-26 10:29:38.970: D/it.domain.myapp.FragmentServices(32540): putData()
04-26 10:29:38.970: D/it.domain.myapp.FragmentServices(32540): putData()
04-26 10:29:38.975: D/it.domain.myapp.FragmentServices(32540): onResume()
04-26 10:29:39.095: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:39.095: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:41.715: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:41.720: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:47.700: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:47.700: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:49.350: D/it.domain.myapp.ViewInformation(32540): ViewInformation()
04-26 10:29:49.400: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:49.400: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:49.495: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:29:49.495: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:30:13.320: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): onResume()
04-26 10:30:13.320: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): TabsFragmentActivity handleAction(): ACTION_NOTIFY_HIDDEN_CALL value=false
04-26 10:30:13.435: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:30:13.435: E/SpannableStringBuilder(32540): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-26 10:30:16.050: W/ResourceType(32540): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)

## Here I pressed the Exit button the second time

04-26 10:30:16.995: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): exit()
04-26 10:30:17.030: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): Starting Unregistration thread
04-26 10:30:17.750: D/it.domain.myapp.XTabsContainer(32540): onDestroy
04-26 10:30:17.765: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragRecents(32540): onDestroy
04-26 10:30:17.770: D/it.domain.myapp.TabFragContacts(32540): onDestroy()
```

Comment: Why not just do the cleaning up in your `onDestroy()` and let Android handle the Activity Lifecycle?

Comment: post the content of your ExitThread. Also, are there any other messages in the logcat that are interesting (crashes, errors, etc.)? Don't filter the logcat because you may miss something important.

Comment: @tolgap Thanks but in my app the Service can run even if the main Activity is destroyed. The only case when they both need to be destroyed is when the user really wants to exit from the app.

Comment: Ok, but your problem is that you want to asynchronously shut down your things. This means that your activity will finish, while the ExitThread is still running and cleaning things up. Don't make that a thread, or let your activity wait for a callback from the ExitThread

Comment: @David Wasser: Added the code of ExitThread. Unfortunately I didn't save the unfiltered log. I'll update the post if I reproduce this again. Thanks.

Comment: @tolgap Got your point. I added the code to wait for closing things up in the onDestroy method. I'll let you know if the problem occurs again. Thanks.

Comment: may be this a problem of memory leak. try making you ExitThread class static.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Handler.post()` which means that the code in your `ExitThread` isn't actually running in another thread, it is running on the main (UI) thread. You have a loop in your `ExitThread` that sleeps. This is not good to run on the UI thread, as it blocks the UI. Android will eventually kill this activity with an ANR (Application Not Responding) error.

You need to actually run the stuff in your `ExitThread` in a separate thread. Instead of:

```
mHandler.post(new ExitThread());
```

do:

```
new ExitThread().start();
```